# Typesafe Console not connecting to app

Tags: console, akka, typesafe

I am trying to use the typesafe console on an application that I have.  Bear with the explanation, but it is important to get the context

My application is a web application.  It has a maven dependency on a jar that uses akka (in other words, the web app doesn't interact akka directly, the akka stuff is transparent to the web app).

I have downloaded typesafe-console developer 1.3.1.

I added the load time weaver to the jvm arguments, my startup arguments look like:

```
-javaagent:/opt/typesafe-console-developer-1.3.1/lib/weaver/aspectjweaver.jar
-Dorg.aspectj.tracing.factory=default
-Djava.library.path=/opt/typesafe-console-developer-1.3.1/lib/sigar
-Daj.weaving.verbose=true
```

I do get some weaving output, and it does indicate that it is using the aop.xml in the trace-akka jars.

My application starts up just fine in tomcat, everything runs dandily.

However, when I go to the typesafe console, I don't see anything there.

I did create an application.conf file in my web application like so:

```
akka {
    loggers = ["com.typesafe.atmos.trace.Slf4jTraceContextLogger"]
    loglevel = "INFO"
}


atmos {
    trace {
        enabled = true
        traceable {
            "*" = on
        }

    sampling {
        "*" = 1
    }
}}
```

My guess is that I missed a step someplace, or perhaps the application config file is not getting picked up?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It was the application config file was not being loaded.

I just had a little hack to override the application config file for akka and it worked!